# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in /node_modules/react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js:23

Tags: react-native, jenkins, jestjs

I wrote the unit test cases for my react-native app. Its working fine locally. All the test cases are passed. But when I try to implement this test cases in Jenkins then its not working and getting error. Give suggestions on this.

Jenkins Shell Script:
npm install
npm test

```
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/#####/workspace/node_modules/react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js:23
);
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at new HasteMap     (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/#####/workspace/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:428:25)
```

Comment: Found the solution. Node version is different in Jenkins. Need to install the latest node version